# How to achieve hierarchical taxonomy url structure for custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks

I'm working on multi language Wordpress site with custom post type (eg. Cars) and I have trouble with creating right url structure.

I'm not using any plugin for translations (I find all of them a kinda overkill), I want it to be managed with categories, where each category will represent one language (EN, FR, ES etc.)

The permalink then should look like this:

```
// eg.: /en/cars/bmw
/$category_slug/cars/$post_slug
```

This can be easily achieved with default post type through permalink administration, but I can't get it work with custom types.

The closest I got is:

```
// eg.: /cars/en/bmw
/cars/$category_slug/$post_slug
```

with this settings:

```
register_post_type('cars', array(
    'rewrite'  => array(
        'slug' => 'cars/%cars_taxonomy%' // "cars_taxonomy" is the name of my taxonomy for function register_taxonomy()
    )
);
```